# Flask/Werkzeug how to attach HTTP content-length header to file download

Tags: python, http-headers, download, flask, werkzeug

I am using Flask (based on Werkzeug) which uses Python.

The user can download a file, I'm using the [`send_from_directory`-function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=send_from_directory#flask.send_from_directory).

However when actually downloading the file, the HTTP header `content-length` is not set. So the user has no idea how big the file being downloaded is.

I can use `os.path.getsize(FILE_LOCATION)` in Python to get the file size (in bytes), but cannot find a way to set the `content-length` header in Flask.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you'd do something like this (untested):

```
from flask import Response
response = Response()
response.headers.add('content-length', str(os.path.getsize(FILE_LOCATION)))
```

See: [Werkzug's Headers object](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/dev/datastructures.html#werkzeug.Headers) and [Flask's Response object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#response-objects).

Answer (score 40):

I needed this also, but for every requests, so here's what I did (based on the doc) :

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

Answer (score 39):

Since version 0.6 the canonical way to add headers to a response object is via the `make_response` method (see [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.make_response)).

```
def index():
    response = make_response(render_template('index.html', foo=42))
    response.headers['X-Parachutes'] = 'parachutes are cool'
    return response
```