# How to send image generated by PIL to browser?

Tags: python, streaming, python-imaging-library, flask, temporary-files

I'm using flask for my application. I'd like to send an image (dynamically generated by PIL) to client without saving on disk.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Flask doesn't seem to have solid support for streaming binary data that you can't generate with a Python generator. You'll probably have to buffer the image in memory and sent that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, you can save the image to a [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) and remove the local file (if you have one):

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import copyfileobj
from os import remove

tempFileObj = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b',suffix='jpg')
pilImage = open('/tmp/myfile.jpg','rb')
copyfileobj(pilImage,tempFileObj)
pilImage.close()
remove('/tmp/myfile.jpg')
tempFileObj.seek(0,0)
```

Second, set the temp file to the response (as per [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811595/flask-werkzeug-how-to-attach-http-content-length-header-to-file-download)):

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/path')
def view_method():
    response = send_file(tempFileObj, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='myfile.jpg')
    return response
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore: `TypeError: 'file' object is not callable`

Comment: Which is the dynamically created file over here?

Comment: @user1953366 - in this example, the file being created is myfile.jpg, but I would seriously check out mr-mr's answer below, as it is much more efficient without the need to create a temporary file.

Comment: temp files are also written to disk? how is this the accepted response?

Answer (score 184):

Here's a version without any temp files and the like (see [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/32/)):

```
from io import StringIO

def serve_pil_image(pil_img):
    img_io = StringIO()
    pil_img.save(img_io, 'JPEG', quality=70)
    img_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

To use in your code simply do

```
@app.route('some/route/')
def serve_img():
    img = Image.new('RGB', ...)
    return serve_pil_image(img)
```

Comment: Means you have to be able to hold the whole image in memory at once though, right? Might be an issue with huge images or other types of downloads.

Comment: @Eli for those cases it seems more sensible to use a temporary file. Anyway, huge dynamically generated files aren't common.

Comment: This is a great solution for generating files in memory

Comment: How do I insert it into the template I am returning?

Comment: How would one add headers to this? Since we are not using make_response?

Comment: Use on the side of caution. Some wsgi implementations require a `fileno()` method for sendfile, and StringIO objects has no `fileno()` method.

Comment: Assuming you're doing `import StringIO` you'll need to change a line: `img_io = StringIO.StringIO()`

Comment: For python3 it's io.BytesIO (not ByteIO)

Comment: How would I now reference the file in the `src` attribute of an `img` tag

Comment: for those asking how to reference the file in the `src` attribute of an `img` tag, simply use an endpoint that will serve the images `@app.route('/docs/<filename>')` and then in the HTML use `src="/docs/some_img.jpg"

Answer (score 38):

Mr. Mr. did an excellent job indeed. I had to use BytesIO() instead of StringIO().

```
def serve_pil_image(pil_img):
    img_io = BytesIO()
    pil_img.save(img_io, 'JPEG', quality=70)
    img_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with the fact that BytesIO is not a string and `send_file` requires a string for the path. How can I get the path from the BytesIO object?

Comment: I think bytes come out as a 8 bit object that can be interpreted as a string. Anyways - I'm not really sure why it's not working for you, try StringIO() maybe?

Comment: It actually was working fine, I just wasn't referencing it correctly in my html. Now using `url_for()` and it is working fine.

Comment: I have it setup like that, but when I run my application inside docker i get `RuntimeError: Attempted implicit sequence conversion but the response object is in direct passthrough mode.` Any ideas where to set it?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that flask provides a solution (rtm to myself!):

```
from flask import abort, send_file
try:
    return send_file(image_file)
except:
    abort(404)
```

Answer (score 6):

I was also struggling in the same situation. Finally, I have found its solution using a WSGI application, which is an acceptable object for "make_response" as its argument.

```
from Flask import make_response

@app.route('/some/url/to/photo')
def local_photo():
    print('executing local_photo...')
    with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
        def wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
            start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'image/jpeg')])
            return image_file.read()
        return make_response(wsgi_app)
```

Please replace "opening image" operations with appropriate PIL operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
        return send_file(fileName, mimetype='image/png')
```