# How to run python script as a web service with user provided image?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python(2.7) script which detects faces in an image which works fine.

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition


# Load the jpg file into a numpy array
image = face_recognition.load_image_file("/PATH_TO_IMAGE/IMAGE.jpg")

# Find all the faces in the image
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

# a = print("Found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)))
for face_location in face_locations:

    # Print the location of each face in this image
  top, right, bottom, left = face_location
  print("A face is located at pixel location Top: {}, Left: {}, Bottom: {}, Right: {}".format(top, left, bottom, right))

    # You can access the actual face itself like this:
  face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
  pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
  pil_image.show()
```

Now, I want to make it as a http://localhost:8080/detect so that user can provide an image and clicking on Submit button will display the output. I think there are few ways to do this, either using Flask, Django or Web server. But not sure which is the simplest way to do this and how to go about it. How to take this code and convert into a webservice? What code changes are required? Any code sample will be of great help.

Comment: I updated my answer concerning your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking what a good web framework for python is. Before I was competent, I wrote a `Django` web server and I found it a bit daunting. But then everything was daunting at that point. I've used `Flask` in few projects since becoming an OK programmer. It's fairly straight forward, easy to setup, and well documented, as is `Django`. I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) when I was learning `Flask`. As I understand it, this is really an opinion question, so IMHO I would go with `Flask`, `uWSGI`, and `Nginx` as is in the tutorial. Though, I would encourage you to do your own research and see if the other options suit you and your project better.

**EDIT:** To use this code `Flask` you either place your code directly in a [route's](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#url-route-registrations) function or even better put it into a function or class and import it. EVEN BETTER create a [model, view, and controller(MVC)](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-model-view-controller-mvc-paradigm-summarized-with-legos/). From a cursory glance, it looks like you'll have to [upload the file and save it](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/), and then open it with `face_recognition`. The [`face_recognition` module](https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html) doesn't seem to be able to read data from memory, so saving the file and opening it with `face_recognition.load_image_file("/PATH_TO_IMAGE/IMAGE.jpg")` seems to be necessary. Just to be sure to delete the file after you load it to clear space. Then once you have your `PIL.Image` object, you would return that from your code and then send it with the `flask.send_file` function as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170635/5854907). Lots of links and no code, but these links along with the tutorial I linked to initially should get you where you need to go.

**Note:** In case it wasn't clear, your code should return `Image.fromarray(face_image)` and not use the `show` function.

Comment: Thanks @allie-fitter. The question is how do I take this code and make it as a webservice? I don't have much experience with creating a web service. Not looking for pros and cons of web frameworks. Hope this clarifies.