# How to download a PIL Image created on a Flask server to my desktop. Image.save() only saves it to the server. Cant access the image by URL

Tags: python, image, flask, python-imaging-library, pythonanywhere

So I create a PIL Image and it is saved to the server. This would be fine and dandy however I would like to avoid saving these images to the server if possible and rather to just the user's desktop. I tried looking up ways to download files however almost all of them seem to involve a url, which is not applicable in my situation.

My code:

```
@app.route('/createAlbumStory', methods = ['GET'])
def create_album_story():
    album = scrapeAlbumDB()
    albumDict = json.loads(album)
    items = albumDict
    user = str(session['username']) + "_createdAlbumStory.jpeg"
    width, height = (1080, 1920)
    img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), (33, 33, 33))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    # font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("/home/Spotify365/mysite/GothamBold.ttf", 50)
    fontB = ImageFont.truetype("/home/Spotify365/mysite/GothamBold.ttf", 30)
    # topText = str(session['username']) + "'s Top 5 Played Albums"
    topText = "user's Top 5 Played Albums"
    tW, tH = draw.textsize(topText, font)
    draw.text(((width - tW)/2, 100), topText ,(255, 255, 255),font)
    # NEED TO CHECK IF THIS LOCAL TRACK IF SO SHIFT TO NEXT ARTIST
    # img.paste(topSongImage, (340, 250))
    for i in range(0, 5):
        topSongImage = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(items[i][1][1]))
        topSongImage = topSongImage.resize((200, 200))
        img.paste(topSongImage, (100, 250 + (i * 300) - 50))
        draw.rectangle(((325, 200 + (i * 300)), (975, 400 + (i * 300))), fill="white")
        songText = str(items[i][0][0]) + "-" + str(items[i][0][1])
        position = (350, 300 + (i * 300) - 50)
        draw.text(position, songText, (0, 0, 0), fontB)
        timeText = str(convert(items[i][1][0]))
        position = (350, 375 + (i * 300) - 50)
        draw.text(position, timeText, (0, 0, 0), fontB)
    adText = "Generated by Spotify365"
    tW, tH = draw.textsize(adText, font)
    draw.text(((width - tW)/2, 1670), adText ,(255, 255, 255),font)
    userText = "@spotify_365"
    tW, tH = draw.textsize(userText, font)
    # draw.text(((width - tW)/2, 1820), userText ,(255, 255, 255),font)
    img.save(user)
    return str(user)
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877282/how-to-send-image-generated-by-pil-to-browser#answer-51986716) is an answer for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, i don't know about saving it to the desktop, however you could definitely make them download it:

```py
return send_from_directory(directory=folder, filename=filename)
```

Where the `directory` is the folder, and `filename` is the name of the file you are sending

This would probably mean that you would have to save it to file first though, so there may be a better way to do this.

You can use this thread for more info:
[Flask Download a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577349/flask-download-a-file)

Comment: Thanks, that flask thread helped alot. Returning the image as: send_file(image, as_attachment=True) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

answer:

```
send_file(image, as_attachment=True)
```

as-attachment specifically is what will download the file to your desktop