# Is there a way in PIL to save an image as an URL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to invert an image using PIL (python-imaging-library) and PIL.ImageOps, can I somehow save that image as a URL so I can enter it into my web browser?

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877282/how-to-send-image-generated-by-pil-to-browser, is this your answer?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Do you want to create a URL for serving on the web, e.g. ``https://www.example.com/some_image.jpg``, a URL for serving locally, e.g. ``https://127.0.0.1/some_image.jpg``, or a just any URI that can be used by a browser, e.g. ``file://tmp/some_image.jpg``?

Answer (score 1):

If by 'as a URL' you mean for the image to be hosted using some web service, I would use something like a Google Cloud Platform or AWS Bucket. Note that these will require a credit card, but offer free trials so you have a few months with which to experiment.

Set up a GCP Bucket and download the credentials file and name is something like 'auth.json'. After saving the PIL file to disk, you would then be able to upload to your bucket with the following code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import uuid

def upload_image(img_path, ext):
    # uploads a single image with given path and ext up to a gcp bucket
    if ext != "png" and ext != "jpg":
        print("only .png and .jpg filetypes are supported")
        return
    storage_client = storage.client.Client.from_service_account_json(
        "AUTHFILE.json", project="PROJECTNAME")
    # using the passed in credentials from the json file, access the GCP project
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("BUCKETNAME")
    # grab the bucket from the project
    path = img_path
    # path to the image
    imageID = uuid.uuid4()
    blob = bucket.blob(f"FOLDERNAME/{imageID.hex}.{ext}")
    # make the name into a uuid (so its unique every time), hex so its shorter
    if ext == "jpg":
        blob.content_type = "image/jpeg"
    else:
        blob.content_type = "image/png"
    # make sure file extension and blob type match
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        blob.upload_from_file(f)
    print(f"Image successfully uploaded as {imageID.hex}.{ext}.")


upload_image("myImage.png", "png")
```

If you want to make it publicly visible, change the permissions of `allUsers` under the `Permissions` tab.
Here is an example image hosted on the web using a GCP Bucket: https://storage.googleapis.com/digichef/images/f7bd821df9a6429e8656f24bd21b458a.png

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this question, you might have misunderstood what is considered a "URL".

URL does not only include absolute paths (like `https://www.stackoverflow.com`). It also includes relative paths. Examples of relative paths are `file.txt` and `c:/Documents/school/financial.xls`.

Mostly, you can view a file with `file:///` plus a full path. The second example I listed above is a full path. Please check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) for additional information.

If you want to put your photo on the internet, use a third-party service. Cubeupload is the one I use, but feel free to experiment with others and see which one you like the most.