# Browser caching issues in flask

Tags: python, caching, flask, browser-cache

I have built a website using flask ([www.csppdb.com](http://www.csppdb.com)). Sometimes when I log in as one user, log out, then login as another user I still see pages from the first user I logged in as. This problem is immediately fixed when the page is refreshed. I think this is called "caching" if I am not mistaken. Is there any way I could disable this on a site wide level so that every page that is visited needs a new refresh?

It would be like sharing your computer with a friend. He logs into Facebook, then logs out. Now you log in on his computer and you see his profile... (awkward). After you refresh the page the problem is fixed.

Here is some of my code. I was using flask-login but I then tried to "roll my own"

```
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, session, url_for, redirect, \
     render_template, g, flash
from data import *
from werkzeug import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
import config

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_USER' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_USER
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] if 'MYSQL_DATABASE_DB' in os.environ else config.MYSQL_DATABASE_DB

mysql.init_app(app)

if 'SECRET_KEY' in os.environ: app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
else: app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

def connect_db(): return mysql.connect()

def check_auth():
    g.user = None
    if 'username' in session:
        g.user = get_user(session['username'])
        return
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/')
def home(): 
    if 'username' in session: return redirect(url_for('main'))
    return render_template('home.html')

def connect_db(): return mysql.connect()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    if exception: print exception
    g.db.close()

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    print session.keys(), session.values()
    print("before request")
    print ('username' in session, "in session?")
    g.db = connect_db()
    g.user = None
    if "username" in session:
        g.user = get_user(session['username'])


@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    """Logs the user in."""
    if 'username' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('main'))

    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("login hit")
        user = get_user(request.form['username'])
        if user is None:
            error = 'Invalid username'
            print error
        elif not check_password_hash(user.password, request.form['password']):
            error = 'Invalid password'
            print error
        else:
            flash('You were logged in')
            print "logged in"
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            g.user = request.form['username']
            print error, "error"
            return redirect(url_for('main'))

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Comment: Nobody can't say you anything before you don't place here any code, for example login and logout views and example of template where this bug.

Comment: @Denis, please see the attached code

Comment: How does a user log out? The code isn't included and I wondered how you were handling the session.

Comment: logout is just popping the user out of the session. session.pop('username', None)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Setting the cache to be max-age=0 fixed it.

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    """
    Add headers to both force latest IE rendering engine or Chrome Frame,
    and also to cache the rendered page for 10 minutes.
    """
    response.headers['X-UA-Compatible'] = 'IE=Edge,chrome=1'
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
    return response
```

Comment: from MDN docs it looks like `no-store` is the only thing required, and is better practice to put only that when settings `Cache-Control`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control. I.e. `Cache-Control: no-store` in the server response to prevent caching. `max-age=0` is implied.

Answer (score 3):

To stop browser caching on these sort of pages you need to set some HTTP response headers.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
```

Once you do this then the browser wont cache those pages. I dont know how to do this with "flask" so I will leave that as an exercise for you :)

This question shows how to add a response header [Flask/Werkzeug how to attach HTTP content-length header to file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811595/flask-werkzeug-how-to-attach-http-content-length-header-to-file-download)

Comment: This http header should be set in the http response from the server

Comment: @Dave updated answer to include a question that shows how to add response headers