# Flask Server on Raspberry Pi Not Properly Rendering CSS

Tags: python, css, flask

I have a fresh install of Jessie on a brand new raspberry pi, and i have installed all the required stuff for the flask server to work, and it does, but the CSS is not properly being rendered. It is properly referenced in the static directory, and has no 404 errors, but it just won't work. Any help is appreciated and thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Hub</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="/static/hub/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='statichub//css/main.css') }}">
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/hub/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/hub/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header">
                        <h1><a href="index.html">Welcome To The Hub</h1>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#footer" class="icon fa-info-circle">About</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </header>

                <!-- Main -->
                    <div id="main">
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="/static/hub/images/fulls/01.jpg" class="image"><img src="/static/hub/images/thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>Magna feugiat lorem</h2>
                            <p>Nunc blandit nisi ligula magna sodales lectus elementum non. Integer id venenatis velit.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="/static/hub/images/fulls/02.jpg" class="image"><img src="/static/hub/images/thumbs/02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>Nisl adipiscing</h2>
                            <p>Nunc blandit nisi ligula magna sodales lectus elementum non. Integer id venenatis velit.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="/static/hub/images/fulls/03.jpg" class="image"><img src="/static/hub/images/thumbs/03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>Tempus aliquam veroeros</h2>
                            <p>Nunc blandit nisi ligula magna sodales lectus elementum non. Integer id venenatis velit.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="/static/hub/images/fulls/04.jpg" class="image"><img src="/static/hub/images/thumbs/04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>Aliquam ipsum sed dolore</h2>
                            <p>Nunc blandit nisi ligula magna sodales lectus elementum non. Integer id venenatis velit.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="/static/hub/images/fulls/05.jpg" class="image"><img src="/static/hub/images/thumbs/05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>Cursis aliquam nisl</h2>
                            <p>Nunc blandit nisi ligula magna sodales lectus elementum non. Integer id venenatis velit.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="/static/hub/images/fulls/06.jpg" class="image"><img src="/static/hub/images/thumbs/06.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>Sed consequat phasellus</h2>
                            <p>Nunc blandit nisi ligula magna sodales lectus elementum non. Integer id venenatis velit.</p>
                        </article>
                        <article class="thumb">
                            <a href="/static/hub/images/fulls/07.jpg" class="image"><img src="/static/hub/images/thumbs/07.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                            <h2>Mauris id tellus arcu</h2>
                            <p>Nunc blandit nisi ligula magna sodales 

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="/static/hub/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/static/hub/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/static/hub/js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/static/hub/js/util.js"></script>
            <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="/static/hub/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="/static/hub/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS file is too large to paste here and is at https://pastebin.com/ZiBbaUfV

My python app script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks!

Comment: I think you have a typo on line 8, where you have the filename. you should just check that first.

Comment: Maybe try adding [cache-control headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768007/browser-caching-issues-in-flask) with `max-age=0`.